# Flutter Web to update address bar url when switch to BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have used the BottomNavigationBar on flutter WEB and added view (StatelessWidget class) on BottomNavigationBarItem. When I am switching to view I need to update address URL.

**For example:**
BottomNavigationBarItem to added below option item

- home
- payment
- guide
- setting

When I'm first launch then it will be home view then URL is
http://localhost:64289/#/home
When i'm switch to payment view then URL will be the same(Not updating).

But I need the URL should be like below
http://localhost:64289/#/payment

I have used the [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) if anyone can give answer Getx as well then it is fine.

I have tried out the Get.toNamed('/payment'); OR  Navigator.pushNamed(context, routeName) as well but in that case, I need to set and bottom bar on each page. so please help me any other way to achieve it.

Comment: have a look: https://sellsbrothers.com/understanding-flutter-deep-links-on-the-web

Comment: Can you please share your relevant code or sample app?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use persistent navbar using named routes then here's the solution:
https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/799#issuecomment-730719165

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have verified but URL Path is not updated when switching to the bottom navigation item.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  static const MAIN_PAGE = '/main-page/:id';
```

In Routes and set

```
initialRoute: "/main-page/0"
```

In GetMaterialApp(main.dart) and set

```
var parameters = Get.parameters;
tabIndex.value = int.parse(parameters['id'].toString());
```

In onInit(MainPageController)

Finally add

```
Get.offAllNamed("/main-page/"+tabIndex.value.toString());
```

When change tab.